# Reload fragment/activity (or recyclerview) from adaptater

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a simple app with fragment and activity hosting a recyclerview, vith data fom a database, i have a delete function, but i can't refresh the recycler view, i tried some method but because my longclick cardview is on the adapter, i can't make it work

this is my adapter:

```
public class LoyaltyCardRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LoyaltyCardRVAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

...

public LoyaltyCardRVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<LoyaltyCardObject> cards) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cards = cards;
}

public void setData(ArrayList<LoyaltyCardObject> cards) {
    this.cards = cards;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cards.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LoyaltyCardObject card = cards.get(position);

    holder.marque.setText(card.getMarque());
    ...
}

@Override
public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.loyaltycard_row,
            parent, false);
    return new CardViewHolder(view, context, cards);
}


/**
 * Cette classe initialise chaque cardview avec l'object correspondant
 */
public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
    CardView cardView;
    TextView mail, marque, code;
    ArrayList<LoyaltyCardObject> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    ImageView logo;

    public CardViewHolder(View view, Context context, ArrayList<LoyaltyCardObject> cards) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { //Gère le clique sur une cardview

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        LoyaltyCardObject card = this.cards.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Codebarre pour la carte " + card.getMarque(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intentcode = new Intent(this.context.getApplicationContext(), LoyaltyCardShowCodeActivity.class);
        intentcode.putExtra("code", card.getCode());
        this.context.startActivity(intentcode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        final LoyaltyCardObject card = this.cards.get(position);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);


        alertDialogBuilder
                .setTitle("Effacer")
                .setMessage("Voulez-vous vraiment effacer cette carte ?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Carte n°" + card.getCode() + " chez " + card.getMarque() + " effacé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.i("MYAPP", "onErrorResponse()");
                            }
                        }) { // Paramètres de la requete
                            @Override
                            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                parameters.put("mail", card.getMail());
                                parameters.put("code", card.getCode());
                                return parameters;
                            }
                        };
                        requestQueue.add(request);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_outline_black_24dp)
                .show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

And my fragment in this exemple:

```
public class LoyaltyCardListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

LoyaltyCardRVAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog dialog;
TextView addCards;
UserSharedPreferences userSharedPreferences;
ArrayList<LoyaltyCardObject> cards = new ArrayList<LoyaltyCardObject>();
String url = ServerURL.CARD_GET;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loyaltycard_list_fragment, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_cards);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new LoyaltyCardRVAdapter(getActivity(), cards);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    addCards = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addCards);

    adapter.setData(cards);

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setMessage("Chargement");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    showDialog();

    addCards.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Ajout de carte");
            builder.setMessage("Comment ajouter ?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Scanner", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i("Alert", "YES");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoyaltyCardAddWithScannerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Manuel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i("Alert", "NO");
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoyaltyCardAddActivity.class));
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

    getAndInitData();

    return rootView;
}

public void getAndInitData() { //Recupère les cartes de l'utilisateur et les affiches dans un recycler view sous forme de cardview

    userSharedPreferences = new UserSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    final UserObject user = userSharedPreferences.getLoggedInUser();

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + user.mail,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            LoyaltyCardObject card = new LoyaltyCardObject();
                            card.setMail(object.getString("mail"));
                            card.setMarque(object.getString("marque"));
                            card.setCode(object.getString("code"));

                            cards.add(card);
                        }
                        hideDialog();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            View view = getView();
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cardlist);
            Log.d("ERROR!!!", error.toString());
            hideDialog();
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar  //Si l'utilisateur n'a pas de carte de fidelite, affiche un snackbar qui propose d'ajouter une carte
                    .make(ll, "Aucune carte", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Ajouter", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                            builder.setTitle("Ajout de carte");
                            builder.setMessage("Comment ajouter ?");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Scanner", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Log.i("Alert", "YES");
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoyaltyCardAddWithScannerActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("Manuel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Log.i("Alert", "NO");
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoyaltyCardAddActivity.class));
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

public void showDialog() {
    if (!dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.show();
}

public void hideDialog() {
    if (dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.hide();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    dialog.hide();
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Where exactly in this code do you want to remove an item?

Comment: @DanielNugent I delete an item from database in the adapter with onlongclick, the problem is I dont know how to detect the delete from the fragment, so I dont know where i should delete it

Comment: I don't see any code in your `onLongClick()` that deletes an item.....

Comment: @DanielNugent sorry, what I mean is i delete from database onlongclick, and my problem is that I don't know how to show the change in the recyclerview, or reload it when i delete from database

Comment: So, where is your code that deletes an item?

Comment: This is my problem, I dont know where to put the code, because the delete from database action is in the adapter class, so i dont know how to detect it and delete it from recycler view

Comment: Your question is still not clear.  If you can't explain where your code is that removes an item, then it's impossible to give you a good answer.

Comment: i have a recyclerview with card inside, each card have a longclicklistener from the adapter class, in which i make a url request to delete the choosed  item, My code for now don't reflect this change in the recycler view and i want to add it, but because i handle the delete operation in the adapter class, i am not able to do it from what i have found

Comment: Wait, is your database on a server?  You can't just call notifyDataSetChanged() locally without getting the updated data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that you can call when the data that contains the adapter has changed. For example:

1. Create your ListView, RecyclerView, ...
2. Create your Adapter.
3. Set the Adapter to your ListView, ....
4. Do the work (change data, delete it, whatever...)

Now, if you want to refresh the actual info that are in the view linked to your adapter, call the method:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That will update the info of your view with the correct and newest info.

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: the problem is that I do the action from the adapter, in the longclicklistener, but i have to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the fragment ?

Comment: Exactly, when you know that the change is done (using a flag, a listener, anything...) in the fragment or where you have declared your Adapter call that method and it will update the data that are in the view.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 steps to remove an item from a RecyclerView

```
list.remove(position);
recycler.removeViewAt(position);
mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);                 
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
```

You have to do this in your Activity/Fragment code.

Comment: but i do the deleting part on my adapter in longclicklistener, how can i detect the change from the activity?